# Scala functional interface traits

Tags: scala

I have a trait:

```
trait MyTrait extends (Int => MyTrait)
```

How can I restrict `MyTrait` in the extends to be any implementations of `MyTrait`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In scala, the `Function` type is covariant as denoted by +R in the Function1 signature:

`trait Function1[-T1, +R] extends AnyRef`

This means that what you have is right already. Having `MyTrait` extend `(Int => MyTrait)` (which is the same as `Function1[Int, MyTrait`) means that any type that extends MyTrait will have to implement an `apply` function that returns any instance of `MyTrait`.

The following would all be legal according to your current `MyTrait` signature:

```
class Foo extends MyTrait {
    def apply(x: Int): Foo = new Foo
}

class Bar extends MyTrait {
    def apply(x: Int): Foo = new Foo
}

class Baz extends MyTrait {
    def apply(x: Int): MyTrait = new MyTrait { def apply(y: Int) = new Baz }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @dcastro. Answer updated. One of these days I will get covariant vs contravariant straight.

Comment: Haha I know, right? Here's how I memorized it: *co*variant is when the two types vary in the same direction: `A :> B` therefore `X[A] :> X[B]`. *Contra*variant is when they vary in opposite directions: `A :> B` therefore `X[B] :> X[A]` (Note: in Latin and some Latin-derived languages, ["contra" means "against"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contra))

Answer (score 6):

As Dan wrote the normal behaviour is to return any instance of MyTrait.

If you want to restrict it to only return an instance of the type of the current object you can do so:

```
trait MyTrait[T <: MyTrait[T]] extends (Int => T)
```

and then when you implement(copying from Dan)

```
class Foo extends MyTrait[Foo] {
    def apply(x: Int): Foo = new Foo
}

class Bar extends MyTrait[Bar] {
    def apply(x: Int): Foo = new Foo //Compile error
}

class Baz extends MyTrait[Baz] {
    def apply(x: Int): MyTrait = new MyTrait { def apply(y: Int) = new Baz }
}
```

Comment: This is called "F-bounded polymorphism"

Comment: I really like this pattern and find it to be very useful. Just a minor note, I think the `Baz` class also won't compile because `apply` must return a `Baz`.